# How exactly does the "Tenacious" badge work?

Tags: support, badges

The description says "Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total".  I understand what zero score accepted answers are, and more than 5 makes sense, but what is "20% of total"?  I'd assumed it meant that the zero-score accepted answers were more than 20% of your total zero-score answers, but I have reason to think this is not so.

Comment: I agree that the wording is awkward.  Perhaps "Five or more Zero-Score answers, making up 20% of your total answers."

Comment: That's not the same as ErikA's answer.  Is there anyone who can tell us what the actual definition is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess it means that the number of zero-score accepted answers must make up more than 20% of your total accepted answers.

Comment: My zero-score accepted answers number 6, and my total accepted answers number 21, so it can't be that.

Comment: My understanding is that, for some badges, the process that calcluates things and awards badges only runs periodically, so give it a few days and see what happens.

Comment: It's been several days, but I hadn't realised that some "badge runs" are infrequent - I'll sit down and shut up for bit (and accept your answer with gratitude if and when the badge shows up!).

Comment: It arrived, you were right.